# Как сделать автозамену слов в textBox?

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте. Есть программа, отправляющая сообщения друзьям, так же есть несколько аккаунтов и вот такой код, который отправляет 5 сообщений на id, которые загружаются в текстБокс из файла:

```
void Go()
{
        var index = 0;
        api.Authorize(4562540, логин, пароль, Settings.All);


        foreach (var login in textBox6.Lines)
        {
            try
            {
                var id = int.Parse(login);
                textBox10.Text = api.Messages.Send(id, false, textBox12.Text).ToString();
                label5.Text = "Отправлено: " + index.ToString();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
                if (index++ == 4)
                {

                    break;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

Вопрос - как после того как наступит `break;` автоматически подставлять новый логин и пароль в текстбокс, чтоб работа нового аккаунта начиналась заново? Отдельно создан файл с логинами, отдельно с паролями. Позиции логина = позиции пароля в файлах.

Answer (score 2):

Я плохо знаю C-подобные, точнее - не знаю совсем, последний раз имел с ними дело 25 лет назад, однако...
Что мешает после `var index=0` перед обращением к API создать еще один объемлющий цикл, который пойдет по строкам в файлах логинов и паролей.

На псевдокоде это выглядит примерно так:

```
//инициализация
открыть файл_паролей, файл_логинов
//считываем по первой строке каждого файла
считать_строку(логин, файл_логинов)
считать_строку(пароль, файл_паролей)
начало_цикла
//вдруг забыли заполнить файл(ы)
  если (eof(файл паролей) или eof(файл паролей)) то прервать_цикл
  твой foreach...
  //читаем следующую пару строк. Если уже прочли последнюю, то будет eof и цикл закончится
  считать_строку(логин, файл_логинов)
  считать_строку(пароль, файл_паролей)
повторять_пока not eof(файл_паролей)
```

Comment: Ответ нужен в виде кода.

Comment: @inkorpus Извиняйте, как правильно читать из файлов и как оформлять циклы while/until - это основы языка. Я вам расписал алгоритм, а реализация уже за вами. Может стоит посмотреть описание языка в разделе "операторы циклов"?

Answer (score 0):

веселый вопрос, насмешил. Что наблюдается? судя по названиям контролов - это фрагмент деасемблированного (т.е. чужого) кода. причем этот код искусственно замедлен и ограничен по количеству попыток. А также видим неосуществимое желание автора вопроса снять это ограничение )))) Ох это страшное слово BREAK